# Inserting value automatically to a colum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I the requirement where there are 3 columns in a SQL server table, the columns are `starttime`, `endtime`, `journeytime`. While inserting table values I enter `starttime`, `endtime` column values; the 3rd column values will be generated from `endtime - starttime`.

How can I do this when creating a table? Thanks!

Comment: Check out computed column.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: Please do not use all-caps for a title. That is considered rude and/or shouting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCtest]
(
    [starttime] [datetime] NULL,
    [endtime] [datetime] NULL,
    [last_date] AS DATEDIFF(MINUTE, endtime , starttime) 
)
INSERT INTO CCTest (starttime, endtime)
SELECT '11:15:00' ,'13:15:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '10:45:00' ,'18:59:00'  


SELECT * FROM dbo.CCTest
GO
```